# "Unknown element" in Strongly typed View with Generic Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble defining generic models in razor views. Whenever I use a generic model, I get the following warning:

> Unknown element 'string' or element cannot be placed here.

Example:

```
@model List<string>
```

While this doesn't cause any major errors, it's still very annoying. Is there a way to define a generic in a razor view that doesn't cause this warning?

Environment: 
VS 2013 
ASP.NET MVC v5.1.2 
Razor 3.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and it turns out that when I upgraded to the latest version of MVC, not all of my config elements were updated correctly. Changing Web.config in the following ways fixed this for me:

1. Make sure any line mentioning `System.Web.Mvc` has the version number changed to `5.0.0.0`.
2. Make sure any line mentioning `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` has the version number changed to `3.0.0.0`.

Comment: That was the weirdest issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while using a generic type and the versions in the web.config were correct. I had to wrap it in the code block to make the warning disappear.

```
@{
    @model List<MyModelType>
}
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of testing this solution, worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too, but why doesn't it work the other way?

Comment: I would like to add that I fixed my issue by updating my visual studio to the latest version.

Comment: un-f*/87ng believable !

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and it was an issue caused by an incomplete upgrade from MVC 4 to 5. The suggestions from StriplingWarrior helped but also required the following change to the root web.config:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

(from version 2.0.0.0)

And a restarting of Visual Studio. Adding those two steps finally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lower case `m`...

```
@model List<string>
```

Comment: Good catch, though that doesn't resolve my issue. I corrected my example code.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error or something different? Perhaps it needs to be fully qualified? `@model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`

Comment: @Dustin E - clean and rebuild the project, it may help.

Comment: It's actually the same error. The example code had a typo. I'm receiving the error on other production code, including fully qualified model declarations.